# How to use local variable as a type

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am working on an angular project with Web API where I need to map an entity **TblEmployee** from form posted values.

I have created a static function **ConvertValue** to dynamic typecasting values, but on calling this function I am not able to pass exact parameters.

Below is my code and I am getting this error on compile time:

> 'propertyInfo' is a var but is used like a type.

```
public partial class TblEmployee
{
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}

public int Create()
{
    TblEmployee employee = new TblEmployee();

    Dictionary<String, Object> _formvalue = new Dictionary<String, Object>();

    foreach (string key in HttpContext.Request.Form.Keys)
    {
        string val = HttpContext.Request.Form[key];
        var propertyInfo = typeof(TblEmployee).GetProperty(key);   

        if (propertyInfo != null)
        {                                 
            var myVal = Filters.ConvertValue<propertyInfo.PropertyType.Name>(val);
            propertyInfo.SetValue(employee, myVal);
        }
    }   

    return objemployee.AddEmployee(employee);           
}

public static T ConvertValue<T>(string value)
{
    return (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T));
}
```

Comment: do you know that you can write your controller action like this `public IHttpActionResult SomeAction(TblEmployee employee) { ... }` and WebAPI will do all "Convert-magic" for you?

Comment: I know that but here I am passing all data including file in formdata and fetching all from Form..

Comment: have you tried `TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T))` ? thats what i use

Comment: check the convertion from generic used here https://github.com/neville-nazerane/NetCore-Apis/blob/master/NetCore.Apis.Client.UI/ComponentStringMapper.cs

Comment: I am already getting that type but need to typecast entity property respectively..

Comment: you may also create a form ViewModel wich contain file (byte[]) and still use out-of-the-box stuff

Comment: I have already tried all these things but was not able to post file from angular 6 form, so using this way I am getting file in controller..

Comment: ok, if you **for sure** need this, just change your `ConvertValue` method to non-generic `public static object ConvertValue(string value, Type valueType) { ... }`

Comment: `<propertyInfo.PropertyType.Name>` would always give you `<string>`. you may want to try using `Type.GetType`

Comment: public static object ConvertValue(string value, Type valueType)
        {
            return (valueType)Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(valueType));
        } , @vasily.sib how to typecast using valueType ..?

Comment: as I see from you code you don't need any typecast. Why do you think that you need to typecast this?

Comment: No I am getting error bcz it return string every time..

Comment: again, you don't need a typecast. You assign whatever is returned from `Filters.ConvertValue()` to a `myVal` variable, and the only place where this variable is used is `propertyInfo.SetValue()`, which don't care about types of his parameters.

Comment: but m facing problem to get value in variable myVal.. that's why i ask the question..

Comment: ok, then just use `var myVal = Convert.ChangeType(value, propertyInfo.PropertyType);` **why** do you need a typecast?

Comment: thanks @vasily.sib, actually I have tried the same but by mistake i didn't pass myVal to setValue, and I do require typecasting bcz without this it gives me typecast error..

Comment: typecast error without typecasting is very intresting:)

Comment: hahaha, its giving me error bcz employeeid is of int32 and I have taken string variable for val.... as i am using asp.net core so may be it can be one of the reasons bcz before this when i was using asp.net web api then i didn't face such any issues..